# Writing data from different clients to separate files simultaneously

Tags: c++, multithreading, client, thrift

I'm right now I have a Thrift TSimpleServer that is going to accept connection from multiple clients at once. Once those clients connect they will be sending data that is to be stored in a respective file on the server. Now I'm pretty new to thrift so I'm not sure how the TSimpleServer handles multiple connections(haven't tested that yet) anyways I'm not even sure how to go about saving the received data in separate files simultaneously. I assume a separate thread is created to handle each client connections but how do give each thread a file path to use?

Answer (score 0):

TSimpleServer handles simply :-) one connection at a time. You may want to use TThreadedServer or TThreadPoolServer which are able to process requests in parallel.

How you do give each thread a file depends on your exact use case. For example, you could consider deriving an own version of a thread factory and register this one with the thread Manager. Although the following blog post does not exactly cover your scenario, you should get the idea from the code at the end of the text:

http://mikecvet.wordpress.com/2010/05/13/apache-thrift-tutorial-the-sequel/